# How to ask Selenium2 to finish loading a page on .Click before doing any assertions?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to use the selenium2 c# webdriver to test our login mechanism. The following test passes if I run through it in debug mode and give the Click method some time. If I run it normally though the test fails with a NoSuchElementException.

```
    [Test]
    public void TestClickLogonLink()
    {
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://nssidManager.local/");
        IWebElement loginElement = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginWidget"));
        IWebElement logonAnchor = loginElement.FindElement(By.LinkText("Log On"));

        logonAnchor.Click();

        IWebElement userNameTextBox = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName"));

        Assert.IsNotNull(userNameTextBox);
    }
```

How do I need to tell Selenium to Wait until the logonAnchor.Click has finished loading the next page?

Answer (score 9):

Set the implicit wait like so:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0,30));
```

This will allow Selenium to block until the FindElement succeeds or times out.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have some extensions methods for the driver:

```
public static class SeleniumDriverExtensions
{
    public static void GoToUrl(this IWebDriver driver, string url, By elementToWaitFor = null)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        driver.WaitUntillElementIsPresent(elementToWaitFor ?? By.CssSelector("div.body"));
    }

    public static void WaitUntillElementIsPresent(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(d => d.IsElementPresent(by) && d.FindElement(by).Displayed);
    }
          .....
}
```

I have div.body on all my pages.

Answer (score 0):

I've made the following extension method to the IWebElement class:

```
public static void ClickAndWaitForNewPage(this IWebElement elementToClick, IWebDriver driver)
{
    elementToClick.Click();
    new Wait(driver).Until(d => elementToClick.IsStale(), 5);
}

private static bool IsStale(this IWebElement elementToClick)
{
    try
    {
        //the following will raise an exception when called for any ID value
        elementToClick.FindElement(By.Id("Irrelevant value"));
        return false;
    }
    catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```